# Solving recurrence equation in two variables

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence,
$$F(n, m) = F(n-1, m) + F(n, m-1) + F(n-1,m-1) $$

$$F(n,1)  = 0$$
$$F(1,n)  = 2*(n-1)$$

I would like to compute $F(N,M)$ in terms of $N$ and $M$. The system is defined for $1 \leq n \leq N$ and $1 \leq m \leq M$ where $N$ and $M$ are non-negative integers.
I have solved many linear recurrences in past, but this type of recurrence in two variables is new to me. I even researched but couldn't find any good research paper involving method of reducing recurrences in terms of variables.

The value of $N$ can be upto $10^3$ and value of $M$ is upto $10^9$.

Comment: @molarmass, can you again edit the question. It conflicted with my previous edit.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Is it for a contest ?

Comment: Solve for $F(n,2)$ then $F(n,3)$, ...

Comment: @YvesDaoust, no it isn't for contest.

Comment: Constraints of m are upto 10^9. This is not asymptotically good.

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [Finding closed form of recurrence relation in two variables](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312544). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) provides, in my opinion, very reasonable advice regarding cross-posting.